# How do I restore a missing project template in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2015, package, nuget, class-library

Since installing the latest ASP.NET and .NET Core in Visual Studio 2015, when opening a project created with the "Class Library (Package)" template, the project shows in my solution as "(incompatible)".

What happened to the template that creates project files with the *.xproj extension?

How do I open previously created projects with this extension?

Comment: Does the "Class Library (Package)" project template means "Class Library (.NET Core)" or a NuGet package Class Library in Visual Studio 2015? Please create a new .NET Core Class Library with current Visual Studio 2015 installation and then re-open it to check whether it also has the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

"Class Library (Package)" is a template for Asp.NET 5 project which use DNX while the latest Asp.Net Core use .Net Core. You can following the instruction here to upgrade the Asp.NET 5 project to Asp.NET Core project: [Migrating from ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/rc1-to-rtm).